# CSS header position:fixed causing body div to dissappear

Tags: css, position, fixed

To keep it short here's the example of the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/2KTFG/1101/

see the first paragraph dissappears behind the header

html

```
<div id='header'>
    <div id="div_1">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <div id= "div_2">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='body'><p>why this goes behing previous div?</p>
    <p>why this goes behing previous div?</p>
    <p>why this goes behing previous div?</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
#div_1 {
       margin: 0 auto;
}

#div_2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#body{ margin-top: 30px; height: 3000px; overflow: auto; }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: I need a fixed header. Freezed always at the top of the page.

Comment: you should select any good answer to close this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set the margin of your body to 30 and the height of the header to 50px.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `#body (margin-top:30px)` is not enough to clear the header. Increase the margin value to push the first paragraph down.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Giving something position:fixed; will cause that element to be fixed to wherever you place it in the browser. Since your paragraph div doesn't have any position styles, the header will be placed on top of it.

If you give each element position: relative; they will stack on top of each other.

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;}
#body{ height: 3000px; overflow: auto;position:relative; }
```

[Example in fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/2KTFG/1104/)